# Customer support ticketing software

Tags: web, community

I am looking for an open source (or relatively inexpensive) customer support ticketing solution. My friend has launched a new software tool to help people learn guitar and is looking for a web-based way to manage the bug reporting process.

He is looking at http://osticket.com/index.php at the moment.

Does anyone have any suggestions, experiences  or alternative solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for what may be called "help desk software" generically. Googling this term should result in some finds, especially if you add "open source" or "free" to the search query.

A search returned what claims to be a "complete list" of all such software that's probably worth a gander: http://www.opensourcehelpdesklist.com/

Depending on what you want, you may find bug tracking software will also fit the bill.

Criteria you should look for are:

- Mature and actively developed tool
- Wide and/or active user base
- Interface that is easy to use
- Easy maintenance and updates
- Simple but powerful plugin system preferably with lots of plugins available

Your definitions of at least a couple of these criteria may be unique to you.